# What is the work-life balance and pay like as a investment banker?

Tags: salary, work-environment, work-life-balance

I'm looking to go into investment banking (IB) or venture capital (VC) after university and have heard many stories about what life is like working in these industries.
My question more so relates to IB as there countless online videos about the exorbitant work hours involved in it, with work-life balance being sacrificed in order to cope. The lack of personal time is somewhat compensated by pay but what are the realistic expectations for pay in these jobs? How do the hours and pay vary as you get promoted from say an analyst to higher positions?

Is there anyone who has come from these industries that could provide some insight into the truth of this?

I'm based in Australia but would like to hear about IB in the US as well.

Comment: This isn't really a question about the Workplace per se, more a question about a specific industry. I feel this isn't the best venue for this type of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: *It depends.*

It depends on the company, department and field of work. Jobs such as `investment banker` vary from organization to organization.

To give you an impression, you can find the job in the following industries:

- financial services companies (banks, wealth management, funds, etc.. )
- commercial companies (mining, woods, coal, etc..)
- non-profit organizations
- associations
- etc..

As such the job looks different from place to place, including expectations in you and hours spent. In financial services and banking the job looks different from institution to institution. At one place it may seem as a noble craft and another place as wild-west stock trading as pictured in "The Wolf of Wall Street". Or at one place it will be a nine to five or market opening until market closure quiet trading experience and at another job it might be a very noisy trading floor experience.

Progress as an investment banker will usually be measured in profit made. Promotions will be done in the form of trading margin (the money you will be able to invest).

Bonuses play a critical role to keep profitable investment bankers at one place and are also used for comparison.

These statements are based on my work experience as an IT professional in the financial industry, banking and international stock trading, where I worked closely with market makers and stock traders for about 5 years.